# What is the problem in my bisection calculation?

Tags: matlab

This code gives me;
Error using inline/subsref (line 12)
Not enough inputs to inline function.

%Bisection Method in MATLAB

%we have 5kg box m=5, and coefficient of friction k= 0.4 and unknown force F=x,

%the box is not moving(g=9.81)

```
 m=5;
 k=0.4;
 g=9.81;
 G=m*g;
 N=G;
 a='x-(k.*N)';
 f=inline(a);

 xl=input('Enter the left hand side of interval:') ;
 xu=input('Enter the right hand side of interval:');
 tol=input('Enter the tolerance:');

 if f(xu)*f(xl)<0
 else
 fprintf('The guess is incorrect! Enter new guesses\n');
 xl=input('Enter the left hand side of interval:\n') ;
 xu=input('Enter the right hand side of interval:\n');
 end

 for i=2:12
 xr=(xu+xl)/2;
 if f(xu)*f(xr)<0
xl=xr;
else
xu=xr;
end

if f(xl)*f(xr)<0
xu=xr;
else
xl=xr;
end

xnew(1)=0;
xnew(i)=xr;
if abs((xnew(i)-xnew(i-1))/xnew(i))<tol,break,end
end
str = ['The required root of the equation is: ', num2str(xr), ''],
```

Comment: There is a lot of code we don't need, already the 12th line causes the problem. In addition it seems relevant parts are missing, I don't get the error using Matlab 2020a. Please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `inline` is getting confused about what the variables are in `a`.  My version of Matlab (and presumably yours) thinks `x`, `k`, and `N` are all variables and it's making a function with three arguments.

Rather than using `inline`, I'd suggest just writing the desired function explicitly:

`f=@(x)(x-(k.*N));`